# How to authenticate on Azure Active Directory via LDAP using node?

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, ldap, adal

I am completely new to this. I have the users on AAD. I need to authenticate them using node js. Can someone guide me on how to get started and how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

As @vibronet said, Azure AD not support LDAP.

There is an offical guide [Azure Active Directory developer's guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-developers-guide/) that introduce how to get started for developer.

For accessing AAD in node.js, MS provides the ADAL for node.js library hosted on GitHub, please see https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs.

Meanwhile, you can refer to these articles below to learn about the scenarios using AAD for node.js.

1. [Web App Sign In & Sign Out with Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-openidconnect-nodejs/)
2. [Register your apps to use an Azure Active Directory Account login](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication/)
3. [Getting Started With WEB-API for Node](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/)

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is not used in Azure AD.
A good starting point for authenticating with Azure AD in node can be found in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/?platform=nodejs&service=active-directory